# My SQL BLOB (LONGBLOB) type corrupting my data

Tags: mysql, blob

I am writing a file to a **MySql** table with a blob type.
There are various reasons why I NEED to do this - I cannot just use the filesystem.

I find that writing the file into the db and then reading back from the db, the file is corrupted.
I can replicate this using SQL and nothing else.
The file should fit easily into the LONGBLOB so I do not think the data is being truncated. In fact the data being read back is larger than the data being written. 
*I have experienced the same issue with BLOB and MEDIUMBLOB too.*

Here is the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Video(
Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ShopAssistant_Id int NOT NULL,
Data LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (ShopAssistant_Id) REFERENCES ShopAssistant(id)
);

--insert data from a file
insert into video (shopassistant_id, data) values (1, LOAD_FILE('/Users/tmck/temp/introduction.mp4'));
--read data back into a different file
select data into outfile '/Users/tmck/temp/ret.mp4' from Video;
```

If we now compare the files, ret.mp4 is bigger than introduction.mp4, the individual bytes have been changed and the file is corrupt and won't play.
The file itself is small, circa 245 KB.

What 'option' in MySql is causing it to convert my data?

Comment: Can you diff the two files and find out what the exact difference is?

Comment: which engine are you using? InnoDB?

Comment: The engine for the table is InnoDB

Comment: If I do a diff I simply get "Binary files ret.mp4 and introduction.mp4 differ"

Comment: If I do a manual compare of the two files using Vim, I see similar but different information, with some bytes represented differently:

ORIGINAL
^@^@^@ ftypisom^@^@^B^@isomiso2avc1mp41....

FILE FROM DB
\0\0\0 ftypisom\0\0^B\0isomiso2avc1mp41....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the answer here
      http://ask.metafilter.com/161415/Export-my-Mysql-PDF-binaryblob-into-a-file

The data was being written correctly, and the select into outfile was mangling the data
The soln is to add some escape hints to MYSQL as follows:

```
   select data into outfile '/Users/tmck/temp/ret.mp4' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '' STARTING BY '' from Video
```